# Output not exporting correct text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been having trouble trying to get my code to export the correct encrypted text. my code instead of exporting the text that had been selected and encrypted it exports a file only containing '[]'

How would I go about fixing this as I am new to Python?

Full code below:

```
import io
import sys
import random
import time
import math


lowbound = 33
highbound = 126

key=str


def offset_factor(key):
    total = 0
    for index in range(8):
        numm = ord(key[index])
        total += numm
    total = total//8
    total = total - 32
    return total

def generateoffset(key):
    total = 0
    for i in range(0,8):
        offsetFactor = offsetFactor +ord(key[i])
    offsetFactor = offsetFactor//8-32
    return offsetFactor

def generatekey():
    key=" "
    for line in range(8):
        randomnumber = random.randint(lowbound,highbound)
        randomchar = chr(randomnumber)
        key += randomchar
    return key

def decrypt():
    file = open(input("Please enter the name of the text file you want "
                      "to decrypt \n(include the extension): "), mode="r").read()
    encryption_key = input("Please enter the encryption key that was used to encrypt this text file: ")
    offset_factor, decrypted_message = 0, ""
    for char in encryption_key:
        offset_factor += int(ord(char))
    offset_factor = math.floor(offset_factor / 8) - 32
    for char in file:
        if char == " ":
            decrypted_message += " "

        else:
            decrypted_character = (ord(char)) - offset_factor
            if decrypted_character < 33:
                decrypted_character += 94
            decrypted_message += str(chr(decrypted_character))
    print(decrypted_message)




def runProgram():
    def choice():
        userChoice = input( "1. Encrypt Message\n"
                            "2. Decrypt Message\n"
                            "3. Exit The Program\n"
                            "Please enter the number of what you want to do:\n>>")
        if userChoice == "1":
            return userChoice
        elif userChoice == "2":
            return decrypt()
        elif userChoice == "3":
            print("Exiting Program")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid Response. Please try again.")
            choice()

    def getMessage():  #Beginning of where the encryption starts 
        print("Enter the file name which you want to Encrypt\n")
        userMessage = input("")
        try:
            filetoencrypt = open(userMessage,"r")
            print (filetoencrypt)
        except:
            print("You have given a file which does not exist. please try again.\n")
            time.sleep(1)


            choice()
        else:
            print("File has been Successfully found.")
            toencrypt = []
            for line in filetoencrypt:
                toencrypt.append(line.strip()) #    
            key = generatekey()
            print ("Key has been generated:" + key)
            offset = offset_factor(key)
            encrypted = []

            for line in toencrypt:
                encryptedline = ""
                for char in line:
                    key1, number, getMessage = generatekey(), 0, ""
                    offset_factor1 = math.floor(number / 8) - 32
                    if char == '':
                        encryptedline +=''


            else:
                encrypt_letter = ord(char) + (offset_factor1)
                if encrypt_letter > 126:
                    encrypt_letter -= 94
                getMessage += str(chr(encrypt_letter))
                for line in range(1):
                    print("")
            NewEncrypt = input("Would you like to make it more secure, enter Yes or No: ")
            time.sleep(1)
            if NewEncrypt.upper() == "YES":
                getMessage = getMessage.replace(" ", "")
                getMessage = ' '.join([getMessage[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(getMessage), 5)])
            elif NewEncrypt.upper == "NO":
                getMessage = getMessage
            else:
                print("You entered an invalid option.")
                exit()
            open(input("Text encrypted successfully. \nWhat would you like to save the new "
                       "file as (include the extension): "), mode="w").write(getMessage)
            print ("File saved.")
            sys.exit()






    userChoice = choice() 
    message = getMessage()
    fl = decrypt()
runProgram()
```

Specifically this part of the code:

```
def getMessage():
    print("Enter the file name which you want to Encrypt\n")
    userMessage = input("")
    try:
        filetoencrypt = open(userMessage,"r")
        print (filetoencrypt)
    except:
        print("You have given a file which does not exist. please try again.\n")
        time.sleep(1)


        choice()
    else:
        print("File has been Successfully found.")
        toencrypt = []
        for line in filetoencrypt:
            toencrypt.append(line.strip()) #    
        key = generatekey()
        print ("Key has been generated:" + key)
        offset = offset_factor(key)
        encrypted = []

        for line in toencrypt:
            encryptedline = ""
            for char in line:
                key1, number, getMessage = generatekey(), 0, ""
                offset_factor1 = math.floor(number / 8) - 32
                if char == '':
                    encryptedline +=''


        else:
            encrypt_letter = ord(char) + (offset_factor1)
            if encrypt_letter > 126:
                encrypt_letter -= 94
            getMessage += str(chr(encrypt_letter))
            for line in range(1):
                print("")
        NewEncrypt = input("Would you like to make it more secure, enter Yes or No: ")
        time.sleep(1)
        if NewEncrypt.upper() == "YES":
            getMessage = getMessage.replace(" ", "")
            getMessage = ' '.join([getMessage[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(getMessage), 5)])
        elif NewEncrypt.upper == "NO":
            getMessage = getMessage
        else:
            print("You entered an invalid option.")
            exit()
        open(input("Text encrypted successfully. \nWhat would you like to save the new "
                   "file as (include the extension): "), mode="w").write(getMessage)
        print ("File saved.")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: which part of the code is not working? the question is too generic

Answer (score 0):

Choice 1 is "Encrypt Message"

```
if userChoice == "1":
    return userChoice
```

but it does not call a encrypt method, in fact there is no `encrypt()` method, it just returns "1".